# How to check if item language version exists in Sitecore PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I am trying to get a list of items which have created version in "en" language in PowerShell script. I am using the following code:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -recurse | Where-Object { $_.Language -eq "en" -and $_.Version -eq 1}
```

My understanding was that if the version will be existing this is the version in "en" language so my query should work, but I see that it returns also items that do not have "en" language version created so I am confused now.

Could someone please explain how can I check if the particular language version exists in an item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had this almost correct.

Instead of checking if current version of your item is **1** (version index) you should check number of versions (and pick these where it's not equal 0)

```
? { $_.Versions.Count -ne 0 }
```

Anyway, there is much easier way to do the same:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -Language "en"
```

With this method you get what you want without additional checks.